# Rock, Paper Scissors with Cecilia

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I just used my pyramid to teleport me into Cecilia's room, where she's calmly bathing. I've noticed her high skills in argument, and now am wondering:
Is it even possible to win the argument? If so, anything special happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can win it, but the result is still the same, she kicks you out.

Comment: You also gain some Charisma XP from winning these arguments.

Comment: 130 XP for me, to be exact (spent some time savescumming)

Comment: @Affine admit it, the only reason you save scummed isn't for the xp but for the off chance that you could stay in the room ;)

Comment: @z' Well duh! There's chests and paintings to be had (I ended up looting the place while character 1 was in "conversation" anyway)

Answer (score 1):

After a massive amount of savescumming trying to win fair and square, I stumbled upon a bug that instantly wins the challenge. Just thought I'd share this for others struggling to win.

1. Start the challenge, chosing either of the options.
2. While character 1 is busy with the RPS challenge, switch to character 2.
3. Switch back to the character doing the RPS.

The RPS challenge UI will be gone, and selecting continue in the dialogue will give you the same EXP you get from winning, and the same response from Cecilia. She will still throw you out.

I've only tried this on my current game, so I can not guarantee that it will work with characters with differing stats, etc.

[Youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4CjwNFptAo)

Comment: They must have fixed this bug because this does not work anymore.